# Http 404 in Spring Boot while trying to access resource url

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I developed a Spring Boot REST API and the URL is: `http://localhost:8080/greeting`

However, when I'm trying to access it, it says

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Mon Mar 19 22:06:54 EDT
>   2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No
>   message available

Here is the example that I used: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Whitelabel error page is the spring boot default error page. I tried same code and it all worked fine for me. Did you do any modification to the code? And also do you see `RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting` statement in your console while starting application?

Comment: Post controller code and full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It says /greeting is not found, it should be redirected to /error page, but there is no error page, so the error shows to you.

You need to focus on publishing rest api /greeting.
You can find more examples with code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons for this to happen

- 1 : you did not facilitate any error handling by `ErrorController`.
  (most recommended)
- 2 : You did not explicitly set
  `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` in your
  application.properties. (just a solutions for beginners)
- 3 : Your
  `@SpringBootApplication` configured class is at same level as your
  controller.  e.g.

`src/main/java/com/myPackage/
    --BootApplication
    --RestController`

You can keep BootApplication one level above in hierarchy and it will also solve your issue (this solution is not at all recommended. It just a option and so to let you know).