# How to create the controller for a specific URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to start from this url, http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1;fileId=1

And I create this controller :

```
@GetMapping("/home/filter/{projectId}/{fileId}")
public String filter(@PathVariable("projectId") int projectId, @PathVariable("fileId") int fileId) {

    System.out.println("Project Id " + projectId);

    System.out.println("File Id " + fileId);

    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

When I test with : http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1;fileId=1 I recive this error :

```
 This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
 Wed Apr 04 17:24:51 EEST 2018
 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
 /home/filter
```

I don't know what to do..

Comment: If you are using spring boot then definitely you are doing one of this please check here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375500/http-404-in-spring-boot-while-trying-to-access-resource-url/49376032#49376032

Comment: hint: `/home/filter?projectId=1;fileId=1` format is different from `/home/filter/{projectId}/{fileId}`

Comment: It need to be like this : /home/filter{projectId}{fileId} ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between **query** parameters and **path** parameters in a URL.

- Query parameters are those after the `?` and are formed as `name=value` (and separated by `&` if there are more than 1 parameter),
  like in `http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1&fileId=1`.
- Path parameters are delimited by `/` (and before `?` if there is any),
  like in `http://localhost:8080/home/filter/1/1`.

For **query** parameters you use the `@RequestParam` annotation in your controller.
Example: For URLs like `http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1&fileId=1`
your controller can look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/home/filter")
public String filter(@RequestParam("projectId") int projectId,  
                     @RequestParam("fileId") int fileId) {
    ...
}
```

For **path** parameters you use the `@PathVariable` annotation in the controller.
Example: For URLs  like `http://localhost:8080/home/filter/1/1`
the controller can look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/home/filter/{projectId}/{fileId}")
public String filter(@PathVariable("projectId") int projectId,  
                     @PathVariable("fileId") int fileId) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Mind the difference between `http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1;fileId=1` and `http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1&fileId=1`

Comment: @larsgrefer Thanks for pointing out. Seems I confused query and matrix parameters. Updated my answer.

Comment: Im just not sure if Spring implements this recommendation: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2

Comment: @larsgrefer I've tested to see if Spring implements this recommendation. And it seems Spring separates the query parameters by `&` only, but not by `;`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Just call the correct URL: `http://localhost:8080/home/filter/1/1`

Mind the difference between path parameters and query parameters.

Your controller mapping uses path parameters, while the URL you are calling uses query parameters

Comment: If i try like this, it works, but I don't understand what is the difference between  http://localhost:8080/home/filter/1/1 and    http://localhost:8080/home/filter?projectId=1;fileId=1

Comment: The first URL has the path `/home/filter/1/1` and no query parameters. the second URL has the path `/home/filter` and one query parameter named `projectId` with the value `1;fileId=1`